# lp -d lp1 -h myfile has two options and one argument or 2 options and 2 arguments?

Tags: command-line, syntax, lp

In "Learning the Bash Shell" by O'reilly (third edition), it is written in page 7:

`lp -d lp1 -h myfile` has two options and one argument.

How come?

I see what I reckon as two options, each one with an argument:

```
-d lp1
-h myfile
```

### Notes

`lp` prints a file (concretely, via a printer, and not on the terminal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While writing this question I understand my mistake, I should read the command this way:

```
lp
-d lp1 
-h
myfile
```

The word myfile is just a file name that we print with `lp` it is not an argument of the `-h` option.